# How to get highest difference between two numbers in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I'm working with NodeJS to create a "Featured Product" widget on a website. I have a JSON object with `SKU`, `price`, and `sale_price`. What's the best way to get the `SKU` of the item that has the highest discount (Difference between price and sale_price)?

I tried doing it by for looping through the items and find the difference between price and sale_price, push the results to an array then get the max, but I cannot get the SKU at that point.

Example of the JSON object that I have:

```
{ "item_number":12341231, "price":"250", "sale_price":"219.99"},
{ "item_number":12341232, "price":"210", "sale_price":"209.99"},
{ "item_number":12341233, "price":"20", "sale_price":"12.99"},
{ "item_number":12341234, "price":"150", "sale_price":"19.99"},
{ "item_number":12341235, "price":"60", "sale_price":"29.99"},
{ "item_number":12341236, "price":"10", "sale_price":"5.99"}
];
```

For example the program would return `1231234` as the SKU of the featured item, because the discount is ~$130.

I just want a quick solution, don't worry about performance.

Comment: so loop over and subtract keeping track of the largest difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is not an issue, you can sort your products in descending order and get the first one from the sorted result:

```js
const data = [
  { "item_number":12341231, "price":"250", "sale_price":"219.99"},
  { "item_number":12341232, "price":"210", "sale_price":"209.99"},
  { "item_number":12341233, "price":"20", "sale_price":"12.99"},
  { "item_number":12341234, "price":"150", "sale_price":"19.99"},
  { "item_number":12341235, "price":"60", "sale_price":"29.99"},
  { "item_number":12341236, "price":"10", "sale_price":"5.99"}
];

const maxDiffProduct = data.sort((a, b) => (b.price - b.sale_price) - (a.price - a.sale_price))[0];
console.log(maxDiffProduct.item_number);
```

Comment: No reason to really sort it. Just one iteration over it is enough. This works, but there are better ways of doing it.

Comment: @epascarello You're right. Although with this, you can get more than 1 featured product if you wanted to.

Comment: @slider I agree with you, and I'm actually thinking about pulling the best 5 and use them later if needed.

Answer (score 4):

You could reduce the array with a single loop and take the one with the greatest delta.

```js
var array = [{ item_number: 12341231, price: "250", sale_price: "219.99" }, { item_number: 12341232, price: "210", sale_price: "209.99" }, { item_number: 12341233, price: "20", sale_price: "12.99" }, { item_number: 12341234, price: "150", sale_price: "19.99" }, { item_number: 12341235, price: "60", sale_price: "29.99" }, { item_number: 12341236, price: "10", sale_price: "5.99" }],
    result = array.reduce((a, b) =>
        a.price - a.sale_price > b.price - b.sale_price ? a : b);

console.log(result);
```